# return Mysql value/s that don't find on table records

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table

```
users
id collection_id
1  xwkoss
2  cw2333
3  oipopp
```

And i run query:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE collection_id in ('xwkoss','cw2333', 'abcdeef')
```

that query work fine and return 2 values existing on table, but i need know, which value doesn't exist on table records example: 'abcdeef', based on search parameters

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table on-the-fly and check with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT user_code
FROM
(
  SELECT 'xwkoss' AS user_code
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'cw2333' AS user_code
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abcdeef' AS user_code
) codes
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM users
  WHERE users.user_code = codes.user_code
)
ORDER BY user_code;
```

Comment: HELLO, THANKS, one question, this is the best method? for 2k parameters on user_code find?

Comment: For 2k parameters you may want to create a real table instead and import the codes.

Comment: thanks for u answer i edited my question and create a real table with 1 column collection_id and work thanks